# Does he pronounce English or French?

Tags: pronunciation

> A **bezoar** is a stone taken from the stomach of a goat and it will
>   save you from most poisons” 
> (Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone,
>   Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)
>
> first reader (Stephen Fry) / bi':zɔ:r /
>  second reader (Jim Dale)
>   / b3zɔɑ’ː/
>  [[audio]](http://audioscraps.tistory.com/175)

The second reader’s pronunciation doesn’t sound like English for me, and suspect whether he pronounces French. Would you check whether it is English or French?

Comment: I think this, though fascinating, is far too abstruse for ELL; I'm going to recommend it be migrated to ELU.

Comment: @StoneyB I've spoken with an ELU mod, who's determined the question is a bit localized for their site. I'll wait for the ELL community to step in and decide if that's true here as well, but I wanted to let you know that the migration won't be taking place. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are quite right to detect a French-ish reading in the Dale pronunciation.

[Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/bezoar?q=bezoar) gives two pronunciations.

- The first is Fry's: /ˈbiːzɔː/.
- The second is /ˈbɛzəʊɑː/. This is closer to Dale's but not the same: Dale palatalizes the /z/ to /ʒ/, reduces the /əʊ/ to /w/, and removes the stress to the resultant second syllable. In effect, it's the second syllable of a word borrowed from the French and still pronounced after the French: *bourgeois*.

I have no idea where Dale gets his pronunciation. It may be a misunderstanding of the second dictionary-licensed pronunciation;  it may be the closest version of the second pronunciation he found himself able to speak naturally; or it may be a deliberate effort to make the word sound exotic. It may even be a pronunciation learned in speech, though I would be surprised to hear that the word was spoken often enough in any modern circle for a reading to become current.

Interestingly, the *OED* observes that

> In 17th c. Eng., as in F. and Sp., *bezahar*, *bezaar* was reduced to two syllables, *bezar*, *beazar*, *beazer* (b*ē*<sup>•</sup>zəɹ), of which the mod. pronunc. would be regularly ((b*ī*<sup>•</sup>zəɹ). The spelling *bezoar* (for *bezaär*) appears to be of mod.L. origin; it has influenced the pronunciation given in dictionaries since the end of last century.

To translate into modern notation: before the end of the 18th century the word was pronounced /ˈbiːzə/; after that (probably from Walker’s 1791 *Critical Pronouncing Dictionary* on), dictionaries gave the pronunciation noted in IPA as /ˈbiːzɔː/.

I imagine most pronunciations for the last century or so have been based on spelling rather than aural experience.